# vbScript eval() With a Function or Sub

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I am trying to accomplish the following:

Let's say I have a function `myFunc(sStr)` which returns a value.

I want to dynamically call that function, which I believed I could do by using one of the build in vbScript Functions `eval()` or `execute()`.

```
Function myFunc(fString)
    myFunc = "some text in a string. " & fString
End Function
```

I want to call that via something like this:

```
sDoThis = "response.write myFunc(""blah blah. "")"
execute(sDoThis)
```

This doesn't seem to work (e.g. the part where I pass in the string to be executed).

I need the string that is to be executed to be dynamic.

Does anyone know if/how this is possible?

Comment: Just tried your code as-is and it works just fine. What you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? What error you get? What exactly happens? You have something else causing the problem.

Comment: You are correct, I had other issues.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `GetRef()` to obtain the VBScript variant of a 'function pointer':

```
Option Explicit

Function appendString(sAppend)
  appendString = "constant head " & sAppend
End Function

Dim oFncPtr     : Set oFncPtr = GetRef("appendString")
Dim sFullString : sFullString = oFncPtr("and variable tail")

WScript.Echo sFullString
```

output:

```
constant head and variable tail
```

This avoids the inefficience and security risks of Eval()/Execute.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I noted in the question that I need to dynamically call functions. I don't believe your solution accommodates that (maybe I am missing something).

Comment: I think you _are_ missing something (unless I'm missing something). The function name (appendString) is supplied as a string. That's a reflective call. Isn't that dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Shadow Wizard is correct. I had some other syntax issues. It does work. Thanks all for the help.